# How to use sendkeys in selenium web driver and c# so it generates unique name and account numbers

Tags: c#, string, sendkeys

I am New to automation with no background in programming.
I am creating a test case to run in selenium where account number and account name needs to be unique each time.
This is what i have.

```
 string ClientName = "Automation" + new Random();
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("XXXX")).SendKeys(ClientName);
```

Comment: To guarantee uniqueness, you can use a Guid: `var clientName=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` Also just as regards the question itself - perhaps clarify the question to remove anything to do with Selenium, since the question itself seems to really be about how to generate unique strings.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. Installed Faker-cs-PCL from NuGet Package Manager.

```
 var ClientName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("XXXXXXX"));
 var name = Faker.Name.FullName();
 ClientName.SendKeys(name);
```